# Are JDBI @bind and bind method free from SQL Injection?

Tags: java, sql, sql-injection, jdbi

I have tested @bind annotation with some SQL Injection attempts and seems like the input is sanitized. For bind method, I am not sure whether it's also true.

Can someone confirm whether my guess is correct with some reference? I cannot find anything from the documentation. Thanks.

Here is an examples for using bind annotation.

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT count(*)\n" +
        "FROM member_preference_value WHERE member_id = :memberId and preference_id=:preferenceId")
int hasUserSetPreference(@Bind("preferenceId") Integer preferenceId,@Bind("memberId") String memberId) throws Exception;
```

Here is an example for using bind method.

```
Update update = handle.createStatement(sqlQuery)
                        .bind("bookmark_id", savedSearch.getBookmarkId())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your examples internally using JDBI parameters binding mechanism which eventually boils down to standard JDBC PreparedStatement `setXxx()` family of methods. 
You can confirm that yourself by tracing JDBI source code from [bind](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/0e47099cd4a88ffcb7e8a8407c60fe6cda9f1d7e/src/main/java/org/skife/jdbi/v2/SQLStatement.java#L302) method to [StringArgument](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/master/src/main/java/org/skife/jdbi/v2/StringArgument.java) or similar classes where SQL query params binding is implemented for every type.
So it's no more dangerous to use JDBI `bind` than to use plain JDBC `PreparedStatement` with `setString`/`setInt`/`setXxx` methods.

Comment: if prepared statements are used under the hood, why should we santize when we use define annotation instead of bind.how does it matter ?